# Build and deploy different projects from the same branch using Teamcity

Tags: git, build, teamcity, continuous-deployment

Using git for version control, I have multiple sub-projects with shared libraries in a single branch of a repository in git. Using TeamCity 2017.x, I am doing a build and it builds the complete project (build script is made that way) every time there is a check-in for any of the sub-projects.

Is there some way to (using TeamCity 2017.x only, and not combined with maven or ant) to build each sub-project independently, whenever a file for that sub-project is checked-in. The project is created in IBM IIB ESQL code and we are using separate component folders for each sub-project.

Also, what is the best way to structure our source control to get an optimal outcome with Build and Deploy using TeamCity and Git. Should we keep the shared libraries in a different repository and make a different project repository for each of the sub-projects and then use git modules to combine all and build in TeamCity?

Answer (score 0):

Let me make sure I understand the current situation. There is a git repository that holds several projects. There is a build configuration in TeamCity with a VCS root on that git repository and a trigger on every commit that builds all the projects.

Am I correct?

I suggest creating a build configuration for each project that will use the same VCS root. On the trigger of each build configuration you can configure paths that will trigger the build in the following syntax

:+path/file.txt
:-ignore-path/file.txt

Comment: Thanks Boris, but how will that help in building each sub-project independently, based on which sub-project file was updated?

Comment: You can configure each build to trigger only when a specific sub project is modified using the filter: :+sub-ptoject1/**